# Is the following sentence still grammatical even though I omitted the verb?

Tags: ellipsis, sentence-usage

> ”OK, I'll tell you the story,” he inhaled deeply, as if his tale would
>   take all of his energy. “It started ...”

So the full version would be something like:

> ”OK, I'll tell you the story,” he inhaled deeply, as if **telling** his tale would
>   take all of his energy. “It started ...”

Is it still understandable/grammatical if I omit the verb in this case?

Comment: OK, he sighed, before jumping into the water, as though the swim across the pool was going to take all of his energy.

Comment: "Telling" is not a verb but a quasi-noun, a gerund.  The subject of the verb "would take" must be some kind of noun phrase, or a clause that acts as the noun phrase, e.g. That he had seen the movie twice already made him reluctant to sit through it yet again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the first is understandable. However, the verb of the sentence is "take", not "telling" because "his tale" is the subject. "His tale" is what would take his energy.